# Array resource: get name of each item in the array

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a xml resource like this:

```
<array name="channel_categories">
    <item name="first">@array/bgt</item>
    <item name="second">@array/bcd</item>
    <item name="third">@array/svd</item>
    <item name="fourth">@array/qwe</item>
</array>
```

How can I retrieve the name of each **item** in java code? I know already `getResources().getResourceName(id)` but this returns the name of each array item. (the name of array bgt for example)

Comment: Hello Saleh, its not possible to retrieve item names in Java code